# Race operator in Combine framework

Tags: swift, combine

Is there an equivalent of the [race](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/race) operator in Combine? It's different from `CombineLatest` in that it doesn't wait for all publishers to emit at least once. A workaround I am using right now is to add `startWith` to each publishers and filter those initial values

Comment: You might be looking for for `merge` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge although it sounds like `race` will wait for the first publisher to emit and then ignore events from the other publisher. If that's the case `merge` is not quite the same

Answer (score 0):

As the comments also stated, you can use `.merge()` and then simply take the first value with `.first()`:

```
cancellable = aPublisher
  .merge(anotherPublisher)
  .first()
  .sink { print($0) } 

//Will print the first value either from aPublisher or anotherPublisher,
//whichever arrives first.
```